# Need to load bootstrap-dropdown.js after bootstrap.js to make dropdown work - why?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

New to bootstrap and `javascript` and was trying to build a fairly minimal example of a dropdown menu.  I am using `bootstrap 2.3.2` which is the current version.  My `css` and `js` are visible in my IDE.  From the `bootstrap` docs it seems that a standard install of `bootstrap.js` contains `bootstrap-dropdown.js` and I can see it in the file.  Yet, I need to have the following for the drop down menu to work:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

Why do I have to load `bootstrap-dropdown.js` separately if it is included in `bootstrap.js`?  Obviously there is something fundamental here that I don't understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Bootstrap website :

> Plugins can be included individually (though some have required
>   dependencies), or all at once. Both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js
>   contain all plugins in a single file.

Both `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` contain all plugins in a single file. you do not need the `bootstrap-dropdown.js` if you include `bootstrap.min.js` or `bootstrap.js` from the [bootstrap page](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html), check this overview on [Bootstrap site](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#overview). i can see that you are including both `bootstrap.min.js` and `bootstrap.js` but only one is enough.
[Check the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/jyy96/503/), only using `bootstrap.js`.

Also, you can download a customized version [from here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html), just according to your need you can add components/plugins and then download the custom build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  What's the purpose of the `min` version then, I guess I don't know?  And you are saying that having them both somehow canceled out the presence of `bootstrap-dropdown.js`?

Comment: The `min` version is minified, good for use in the production because it saves space and can't read the code but normal version is god for development version if you want to read source code and debug.

Comment: Yeah, just dug that detail out of the docs.  I thought I needed everything the standard zip file gave me.  Thanks.

Comment: Also check how you can customize according to your need [from here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html). Welcome :-)

Comment: BTW your demo got broken